# How to connect a Windows forms application to a SQL Server database through a lan network?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have written a Windows forms application in vb.Net (Visual Studio 2010) and my form is completely connected to a SQL Server 2008 database. All things are true when using my program in my machine but when I try to run it by other systems in the network the following error occur:

> A network -related or instance -specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL
>   server. the server was not found or was not accessible......

I have installed framework.net3.5 and Microsoft SQL Native Client

But do not any special settings .

Please help me I need some basic helps because its my first time to do some things like this.
thanks

**Connection string** is:

```
<add name="Mosalasbandi.My.MySettings.Contorol_FaniConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Data Source=Ehsan-PC;Initial Catalog=&quot;Contorol Fani&quot;;Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: i have not written a connection strings i have used the wizard and drag and drop methods

Comment: i have installed sql server 2008 in my pc not in server system i thinks its automatly installed enterprised

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: i have edited my question marc

Comment: Hmm.... can you please run `SELECT @@VERSION` against your database and post results (update your question with it)?

Comment: i'm still waiting marc please

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

Comment: <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />   did u mean this

Comment: No, that's not what I meant - try to execute that SQL command on your SQL Server - from the PC where you can connect to it. I am trying to find out whether you really have the enterprise edition....

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   Apr  2 2010 15:48:46   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Answer (score 0):

connection string as follows

String connstr=@"Data Source=tcp:196.211.164.122\ABC\SUTSVR,1433;Initial Catalog=pubs;User ID=sa;Password=OOPS";

note:
196.211.164.122 remote machine and 1433 port number
ABC is name of the server/workstation that your sql instance live.
SUTSVR is name of the sql instance

in addition to above make it sure that the your Sql instance configure to access remote computer.

good luck!!!!